# Can I do anything about multiple rejected edits by the asker that were just added onto?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

I started editing some and I came across 3 instances of "conflicting" edits

- [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23513921), [revision made by op](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57014472/3)
- [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23502861), [revision made by op](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56994147/2)
- [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23513906), [revision made by op](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/57014649/2)

All 3 of the edits here were rejected and just added on to (rather than improving the edit).

So, 1 question arises: <s>If enough askers reject + copy my edit with additions, will I be punished? If so,</s> What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Related: [What to do when a reviewer rejects and edits with your suggested edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306978/what-to-do-when-a-reviewer-rejects-and-edits-with-your-suggested-edit)

Comment: The rejections were all by Community due to edit conflicts, *not* due to someone (OP or otherwise) specifically rejecting it, so it won't be factored into the edit ban mechanism, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/

Comment: @CertainPerformance All of the edits included mine inside of them. So the askers had nothing to do with that? Also, it still counts against my editor stats (which don't really matter, but they're still there)

Comment: Yeah, it does look strange. When someone with edit privileges chooses to "Improve Edit" or press any of the other buttons in the "Suggested Edits" interface, Community will *not* say "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.". Maybe those without edit privileges see something different when an edit to their post is suggested? It doesn't seem likely that they'd go to the trouble of manually copying the source text of your suggestion when editing themselves

Comment: @CertainPerformance Whenever an asker goes to edit their post and there is a suggested edit, are they presented with the traditional suggested-edit dialog or can they edit on top and save the edit without taking action, hence why it would be rejected?

Comment: There's also some timing involved.  A high rep user can start an edit, then a low rep use makes a quick edit that needs approval, then the high rep user submits their edit.  This will reject the low rep user's edit.  In these cases it isn't unreasonable for the changes made by the low rep user to have been made by the high rep user (along with other improvements).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm it doesn’t look like these fit into that category. The edit descriptions match for the edit made by the asker and the suggested edit.

Comment: So why is this happening? The askers are using my edits/descriptions with small additions. All of the users are not high rep.

Comment: This is quite strange. I'm no expert on edit conflicts but this looks to me like a bug.

Comment: I went ahead and added the bug tag. Hopefully I can do that - if I can't for some reason, feel free to roll back

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a bug or not (although it looks like one), but I can tell you what happens.

Your edits were, as you've already noticed by now, conflicted by OPs edits. However, the way the edits were prepopulated with your edit changes looks like a bug, or at least unintentional, and can be reproduced. This doesn't have to be done by OP, however - it can be done by 2k users as well.

For 2k users, here's a manual repro guide:

1. Find a post with a pending edit
2. Copy the ID of the post
3. Bypass the editing restrictions by navigating to `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/Post ID here/edit`
4. The text fields will be edited to contain the exact changes the pending edit has, and the summary will contain whatever the pending edit had as well.

This can also be done by any post owner, provided the edit conveniently happens to be on their post. Clicking "edit" on a revision (`https://stackoverflow.com/posts/Post ID here/revisions`) does not reproduce this problem - it starts a fresh edit off the revision you picked.

So yeah, those edits are your edits, just submitted by someone else. I can't tell you what happened in the case of your edits - all the posts you edited have OPs with low rep, so there could be a bug in the way edits are handled that triggers the bypass, it could be a websocket issue (OP's client didn't get an update on the edit, and when the standalone editor was launched, it got pre-populated with your edit), or it could be intentional. That being said, I don't see much of a reason why it would be intentional, given the users being low-rep users. I doubt 3 different cases are triggered by a somewhat hidden issue (bug?) intentionally when those users are low-rep.

The client not receiving the edit and triggering the bypass is also consistent with the small additions you mentioned. I'm guessing most of those users have no idea where the rest of the changes came from, unless they saw the review after (again, assuming the websocket disconnect theory holds).

Answer (score 6):

This came about due to the issues reported by Zoe above, and have been resolved in a fix that [was just put into place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355831/51) to redirect users to Suggested Edit Reviews, when they load a page, a suggested edit is made, and then they click to edit.