# How many people have to approve an edit?

Tags: support, edits

How many people have to approve an edit?

I thought I had the privilege to unilaterally approve edits, but now I am seeing this when I attempt to approve edits:

[image: You have already reviewed this item. It needs more reviews from other users to be completed.]

Comment: 2 per [the privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: A single approval for an edit can work if 1. It's the OP themselves who accepts it (they don't need to have the review privilege for that) 2. A reviewer clicks **Improve Edit** - then the reviewer can further change the post and upon completion the original edit would be approved and a new one would be added from the reviewer. Since you get the privilege to review edits when you get the privilege to make edits that don't require approval, there is no chance of endless cycle of reviews.

Comment: If you read the [edit privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). _{....} Two votes in either direction will finalize the action._

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I already figured that out from @RobertLongson's link. I read the page recently, but my reading comprehension has taken a steep nose-dive.

Answer (score 2):

> Two votes in either direction will finalize the action.

From

[**Reviewing suggested edits**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

> In addition, users with this privilege level can also begin reviewing suggested edits (which previously you would have had to suggest). These edits remain in a pending state until they get enough votes to either approve them and make the edits take effect or reject them and discard the edit. Two votes in either direction will finalize the action.

I think it's weird that I can

- Edit without approval
- Improve someone's edit and then take credit for the entire edit without approval
- ...but not unilaterally approve edits

Comment: Improving edits insta-approve, yes, but you don't get credit for the entire edit - just the parts you changed. That is unless you exploit [this bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387153/6296561) actively (I'm not recommending that though)

Comment: Are you talking about something else? If I "improve" an edit, I show up as the person who made the edit. Is there some way to share an edit that I don't know about? Does the edit history actually show two edits?

Comment: You've robo reviewers to thank for not being able to unilaterally approve edits. A group of people who simply click buttons till they get a badge.

Comment: You show up as the editor because you're the last to edit, but the revision history does show two edits, where the one from the edit suggestor is the first. Improving edits is considered approving and submitting a new edit on top of the approved one. Both submissions happen instantly when you're done editing

Comment: TIL: Improving an edit creates two edits